# Why have Live tiles stopped working for my website?

Tags: windows, web, windows-8.1, windows-10, live-tile

I have had [Live Tiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn455106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) working for [my website](http://www.vrijezending.nl) for quite some time, but it seems like after one of the latest Windows Updates they have stopped working on both Windows 8.1 as well as on Windows 10.

Nothing has changed on the website since then. The meta tags are still in place and the xml files are still being provided.

```
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="http://www.vrijezending.nl/ieconfig.xml" />
<meta name="application-name" content="Vrije Zendingshulp" />
```

Has anything changed in the specs since I created these? As I said, they have been working quite a while. Two tiles in particular are updated automatically every day (the "FamilyAltar" links).

I also cannot find any way to troubleshoot LiveTiles. I'd love to see a validator. Is there a place where errors with LiveTiles get logged in Windows?

After searching around it seems like I'm the only one having this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one having a problem with Live Tiles. In particular, I am referring to Windows 10 Edge pinned site Live Tiles. I found that the static ones could not be changed (colour etc.) unless I unpinned them and then deleted their particular folders in C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\PinnedTiles and then pinned them again, but as for dynamic ones with notifications, I can't get them working at all. I have also tried all manner of apparent other solutions, as well two versions of the XML notification code and substituting XML with various combinations of meta tags. As for testing, from what I understand, there is currently no way to debug and things just fail silently.

Comment: Thanks for some feedback at last! (almost exactly one year :-) Guess I'll try to pick this up again now I know where the cache is stored, I might be able to fish more info out of that (see what is being cached at least).

Comment: It looks like they have abandoned the whole feature. If I pin MSN.com, microsoft.com, or msdn.microsoft.com, then none of the tiles show any updates at all. In fact they are not even resizable to the larger size like mine. Can anyone find a site where Live Tiles are still working?